# Merge on columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to make a large dataframe using python. I have a large amount of little dataframes with different row and column names, but there is some overlap between the row names and column names. What I was trying to do is start with one of the little dataframes and then one by one add the others.

Each of the specific row-column combinations is unique and in the end there will probably be a lot of NA.

I have tried doing this with merge from pandas, but this results in a much larger dataframe than I need with row and column names being duplicated instead of merged. If I could find a way that pandas realises that NaN is not a value and overwrites it when a new little dataframe is added, I think I would obtain the result I want. 
I am also willing to try something that is not using pandas.

```
For example:
DF1         A    B
        Y   1    2
        Z   0    1


DF2         C    D
        X   1    2
        Z   0    1

Merged:     A    B    C    D
        Y   1    2    NA   NA
        Z   0    1    0    1
        X  NA    NA   1    2

And then a new dataframe has to be added:
DF3         C    E
        Y   0    1
        W   1    1

The result should be:
            A    B    C    D    E
        Y   1    2    0    NA   1
        Z   0    1    0    1    NA
        X   NA   NA   1    2    NA
        W   NA   NA   1    NA   1

But what happens is:
            A    B    C_x    C_y    D    E
        Y   1    2    NA     1      NA   1
        Z   0    1    0      0      1    NA
        X   NA   NA   1      1      2    NA
        W   NA   NA   1      1      NA   1
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Comment: `merge` can get the job done, but you'll need to do some cleaning after every merge to correctly fill the null-values. You may want to look into [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `DataFrame.combine_first`, which will align the DataFrames based on index, and will prioritize values in the left DataFrame, while using values in the right DataFrame to fill missing values.

```
df1.combine_first(df2).combine_first(df3)
```

---

#### Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,0], 'B': [2,1]})
df1.index=['Y', 'Z']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1,0], 'D': [2,1]})
df2.index=['X', 'Z']

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [0,1], 'E': [1,1]})
df3.index=['Y', 'W']
```

#### Code

```
df1.combine_first(df2).combine_first(df3)
```

#### Output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E
W  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
X  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN
Y  1.0  2.0  0.0  NaN  1.0
Z  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Can I split the df1.combine_first(df2).combine_first(df3) command? For example df1.combine_first(df2), and then df1.combine_first(df2) of will that not work? It's because I have a lot of df so I would loop it.

Comment: @Zoem Yes, just make sure to assign it back (or to something else) after every `combine_first`. So you could do `df = df1.combine_first(df2)` followed by `df = df.combine_first(df3)`... Just be careful, because the order in which you do things will be important, since it gives priority to non_null values in the `DataFrame` calling `combine_first`